# Addtional pack size attribute in magento shopping cart price rules

Tags: magento

My catalog contains a number of configurable products where the configurable attribute is a custom attribute called pack_size.

ie: 
T-shirt - single
T-shirt - pack of 10
T-shirt - pack of 25

I need to be able to access this attribute in my cart price rule so that if my rule applies a discount for 100 + t-shirts, this could be achieved by:

100 single t-shirts
10 packs of 10 shirts
4 packs of 25
2 packs of 25 and 5 packs of 10 etc etc...

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: How do you create a pack of configurable products where size is needed too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by building up the *Shopping Cart Price Rule Conditions* for each case. Are you familiar with how to set up a rule like that?

The logic is: Apply this discount if...

if (qty>99 and pack_size="t-shirt") or

if (qty>49 and pack_size="2 pack") or

if (qty>24 and pack_size="4 pack")

The top rule needs to be changed from `ALL` to `ANY` to get the or, or, or. Then in teh sub rules you want a `product attribute combination` rule.  and then set up an additional rule for each pack size and its corresponding quantity. See the screenshot below (I used size in place of pack_size as an example).

You may need to set the pack_size attribute to be useable in shopping cart rules - that is under Catalog->Manage attributes->Attributes and then set `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to yes. then I think it will need a re-index before it will show up as an option in the rule dropdown.

[image: Setting up multiple rule logic]

Comment: Thanks but I have an extra layer of complexity whereby the rule is 'mix and match' - ie: 1 x Product A (pack of 25), 1 x Product B (pack of 25), 50 x Product C (single) = 100 total qualifying products which gets the discount.

Comment: [A third party module](http://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html) might help and I think if I were setting this up I would create an attribute called `pack_count` which can have the value 1, 25, 50, 100 to help with writing the custom code. If you only have a few product combinations you might just get away with coding all the permutations by hand.